# Show that a countable and dense set $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is not closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

> Show that a countable and dense set $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is not closed.
> Deduce that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable.

Hint: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence obtained by ranking the points of $A$ in a certain order, define a sequence of intervals $[b_n , c_n ]$ such that $b_{n-1} < b_n < c_n < c_{n-1}$ , whatever $n$ is, and that $[b_n,c_n]$ contains no point $a_k$ such that $k < n$.

It's hard for me to see how I can define such a sequence of intervals with only the sequence $a_n$. Then I think that I have to apply the Borel-Lebesgue theorem, saying that any compact set A is closed and bounded.

Comment: Even though it seems hard, you should try to follow the hint. It's likely pretty spooky to think about constructing infinitely many intervals all at once, so let's take them one at a time. Start with $[b_1, c_1]$ -- what requirements does this interval need to satisfy? What interval would you like to pick that satisfies these requirements? Then $[b_2, c_2]$ -- what requirements does this need to satisfy? What interval would you like to pick which satisfies these requirements? Etc.

Comment: Let me give you some intuition to see if it helps.  You're trying to create a nested sequence of intervals, each smaller than the last, such that the $n$th interval never contains any of the first $n$ points of your sequence.  You can use the density of $A$ to find such a sequence.  Do you see how?  Once you have that, you need to use the fact that a nested sequence of compact sets has non-empty intersection.

Comment: Start like this: list the elements of $A$ in any way you want. Now, choose a closed interval $I_1$ that does not contain $a_1$. This interval must contain an element $a_1'$ of $A.$ Now choose a second closed interval $I_2\subseteq I_1$ such that $I_1$ has half the length of $I_1$ and does not contain $a_2$ or $a_1'.$ It must contain a point $a_2'$ of $A.$ Continue. You get a sequence of points from $A$ such that at the $n^{th}$ stage of the construction, you have avoided the first $n$ elements of $A$. Furthermore, the intervals are closed and their diameters are shrinking to zero.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk $[b_1,c_1]$ has to be the biggest interval, so if we arrange the sequence $a_n$ to a decreasing sequence, then we should use $a_1$ in this first interval?

Comment: @RobertShore The only idea I had was to order the elements of $A$ in a decreasing way, but until now I still don't know exactly how to create those intervals.

Comment: @Matematleta If we say that the sequence $a_n$ starts at $n=1$, then a closed interval $I_1$ that does not contain $a_1$ will be $[a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}]$ for example? Does this make sense?

Comment: Your sequence of intervals need not (indeed cannot) include all elements of $A$, and you can create it no matter how the elements of $A$ are ordered (as long as the ordering is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb N$).

Comment: @RobertShore Ok then I don't really see how to create such an interval.. Why is it not possibly for this sequence to contain all elements of A?

Comment: Because $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b_0=a_1.$  Let $c_0$ be the first $a_n$ such that $n \gt 0, a_1 \lt a_n$, and $a_0 \notin [b_0, a_n$].  This is only a potential problem if $a_1 \lt a_0$, and in that case, because $A$ is dense, we can always find some $a_n$ between $a_1$ and $a_0$.

Now proceed by induction.  Assume we have $[b_n, c_n]$ as required.  By construction, we know that $a_k \notin [b_n, c_n]$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$.  If also $a_{n+1} \notin [b_n, c_n]$, then let $b_{n+1}=b_n, c_{n+1}=c_n$.  If $a_{n+1}$ is one of the endpoints of your interval, then choose any element of $A$ in the interior of the interval to replace that endpoint.  If $a_{n+1} \in (b_n, c_n)$ (the only remaining possibility), then choose $a \in A$ such that $a \in (b_n, a_{n+1})$ and define $b_{n+1}=b_n, c_{n+1}=a$.  Again, such an $a$ always exists because $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.  This completes the inductive step.

You now have a nested series of compact sets.  The intersection of such a series cannot be empty.  But by construction, that intersection can't contain any element of $A$.

The intersection is in each interval, and the intersection of a set of nested intervals is either a single point $x$ (in which case the endpoints of the intervals converge to that intersection) or is itself an interval.  But the latter case can't happen because we've proved the intersection can't contain any elements of $A$, which is dense in $\Bbb R$.  Thus, the point in the intersection is the limit of the (left) endpoints of our intervals, which all are elements of $A$; in other words, $\lim b_n = x$.  Thus, we have a convergent sequence of elements of $A$ whose limit is not in $A$.  Therefore, $A$ cannot be closed.

Comment: Thank you so much! very clear and understandable answer.

Comment: I think that I have not quite understood how we define the convergent sequence?

Comment: The elements in the intervals are not elements of A so the intersection is not in A. This is clear. But I don’t see why exactly we can say that we have a convergent sequence of elements of A. The only thing we know is that the elements of A are not in the intervals that we defined.

Comment: The intersection is in each interval, and the intersection of a set of nested intervals is either a single point (in which case each endpoint converges to that intersection) or is itself an interval.  But the latter case can't happen because we've proved the intersection can't contain any elements of $A$, which is dense in $\Bbb R$.